# OrientDB Traverse Sum and Group By Top-Most Record

Tags: orientdb

We have Orders that include "caused_order" edges from Order to Order because friends can refer other friends to make purchases. We know from the links we generate for the friends that Order ID 42 caused Order ID 47, so we create a "caused_order" edge between the two Order vertices.

We're looking to identify the people that are generating the most referral business. Right now we just loop through in C# and figure it out because our datasets are relatively small. But I'd like to figure out if there's a way to use the Traverse SQL to accomplish this instead.

The problem I'm running in to is getting an accurate count/sum for each Original Order ID.

Consider the following scenario:

Order 42 caused four other Orders, including Order 47. Order 47 caused 2 additional Orders. And Order 51, unrelated to 42 or 47, caused 3 Orders.

I can run the following SQL to get the best referrers for this specific {ProductId}:

```
select in_caused_order[0].id as OrderID, count(*) as ReferCount, sum(amount) as ReferSum
from ( traverse out('caused_order') from Order ) 
where out_includes.id = '{ProductId}' and $depth >= 1 
group by in_caused_order[0].id
```

**EDIT**: the schema is a bit more complex than this, I was just including the out_includes WHERE clause to show that there's a bit of filtering of the Orders. But it's a bit like:

```
Product(V) <-- includes(E) <-- Order(V) --> caused_order(E) --> Order(V)
(the Order vertex has "amount" as a property, which stores the money spent and is being SUM'd in the SELECT, along with a few fields like date which aren't important)
```

But that will result in something like:

```
OrderID  |  ReferCount  |  ReferSum
42       |  4           |  525
47       |  2           |  130
51       |  3           |  250
```

Except that's not quite right, is it? Because Order 42 also technically caused 47's two orders. So we'd want to see something like:

```
OrderID  |  ReferCount  |  ReferSum  |  ExtendedCount  |  ExtendedSum
42       |  4           |  525       |  2              |  130
47       |  2           |  130       |  0              |  0
51       |  3           |  250       |  0              |  0
```

I recognize that the two "Extended" count/sum columns might be tricky. We might have to run the query twice, once with $depth = 1, and again with $depth > 1, and then assemble the results of those two queries in C#, which is fine.

But I can't even figure out how to get the overall total calculated correctly. The first step would even be to see something like:

```
OrderID  |  ReferCount  |  ReferSum
42       |  6           |  635       <-- includes its 4 orders + 47's 2 orders
47       |  2           |  130
51       |  3           |  250
```

And since this can be n-levels deep, it's not like I can somehow just do in_caused_order.in_caused_order.in_caused_order in the SQL, I don't know how many deep that will go. Order 83 could be caused by Order 47, and Order 105 could be caused by Order 83, and so on.

Any help would be much appreciated. Or maybe the answer is, Traverse can't handle this, and we'll have to figure something else out entirely.

Comment: I'd like to help, but your domain is not clear to me. What is `out_includes`? Could you attach a diagram that explain relationships and attributes?

Comment: @Lvca hi, it's just an out edge to the Product vertex (which is a simplification of our schema, but I wanted to show there's also a WHERE clause in there to filter which Orders we're selecting). I've updated the post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying your usecase, following is my testdata:

```
create class caused_order extends e
create class Order extends v
create property Order.id integer
create property Order.amount integer

begin
create vertex Order set id=1 ,amount=1
create vertex Order set id=2 ,amount=5
create vertex Order set id=3 ,amount=11
create vertex Order set id=4 ,amount=23
create vertex Order set id=5 ,amount=31
create vertex Order set id=6 ,amount=49
create vertex Order set id=7 ,amount=4
create vertex Order set id=8 ,amount=74
create vertex Order set id=9 ,amount=87

create edge caused_order from (select from Order where id=1) to (select from Order where id=2)
create edge caused_order from (select from Order where id=1) to (select from Order where id=3)
create edge caused_order from (select from Order where id=2) to (select from Order where id=4)
create edge caused_order from (select from Order where id=2) to (select from Order where id=5)
create edge caused_order from (select from Order where id=6) to (select from Order where id=7)
create edge caused_order from (select from Order where id=6) to (select from Order where id=8)
commit retry 20
```

[image]

---

then I wrote these 2 queries to show orders with relative referSum and ReferCount.

First one including head order in the count:

```
select id as OrderID, $a[0].Amount as ReferSum, $a[0].Count as ReferCount from Order

let $a=(select sum(amount) as Amount, count(*) as Count from (traverse out('caused_order') from $parent.$current) group by Amount)
```

[image]

second one, excluding the head:

```
select id as OrderID, $a[0].Amount as ReferSum, $a[0].Count as ReferCount from Order

let $a=(select sum(amount) as Amount, count(*) as Count from (select from (traverse out('caused_order') from $parent.$current) where $depth>=1) group by Amount)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**
I've added this to my data:

```
create class includes extends E
create class Product extends V
create property Product.id Integer

create vertex Product set id = 101
create vertex Product set id = 102
create vertex Product set id = 103
create vertex Product set id = 104

create edge includes from (select from Order where id=1) to (select from Product where id=101)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=2) to (select from Product where id=102)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=3) to (select from Product where id=103)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=4) to (select from Product where id=104)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=5) to (select from Product where id=101)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=6) to (select from Product where id=102)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=7) to (select from Product where id=103)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=8) to (select from Product where id=104)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=9) to (select from Product where id=101)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=1) to (select from Product where id=102)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=1) to (select from Product where id=103)
create edge includes from (select from Order where id=2) to (select from Product where id=104)
```

and these are the modified queries (added the `while out('includes').id contains {prodID_number}` in traverse and `where out('includes').id contains {prodID_number}`:

```
select id as OrderID, $a[0].Amount as ReferSum, $a[0].Count as ReferCount from Order

let $a=(select sum(amount) as Amount, count(*) as Count from (traverse out('caused_order') from $parent.$current while out('includes').id contains 102) group by Amount)

 where out('includes').id contains 102
```

[image]

```
select id as OrderID, $a[0].Amount as ReferSum, $a[0].Count as ReferCount from Order

let $a=(select sum(amount) as Amount, count(*) as Count from (traverse out('caused_order') from $parent.$current while out('includes').id contains 102) where $depth >= 1 group by Amount)

 where out('includes').id contains 102
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. the test data looks correct, and your sql results look correct, but when I run it locally, I just get a list of all the OrderIDs in the db, so I'm not sure what's not translating to our instance :( Also, if we wanted to limit it to just Orders of a certain product (the "out_includes[0].id = '{ProductId}'" where would that go in the query?

Comment: thanks. when I run this, I still only get OrderIDs back, without any sums/counts, and I guess I'm still learning about how LET works and joins to the SELECT via $parent.$current? but maybe I'm missing how the sum/count inside the LET get associated to the right OrderID up in the select?